# Restrain usage of APP with GPS

Tags: android, gps, google-apps, android-gps

I was wondering, is it possible to restrain the use of an android APP with the GPS?

Let's say I want that my app is used only in a certain local area no bigger than a couple square miles.

Is this possible? is there an example on this? and what do I need to consider to make it possible?

Thank you all!

Comment: Look for info on geofencing.

Comment: Thanks pal I'll check it out sounds to me this is what I was looking for